# Serving content from MXDs to ArcGIS for Server by publishing from ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service, arcgis-pro

I have 10 ArcMap .mxd's serving content using ArcGIS Server. I have made the switch to using ArcGIS Pro for my all of my analysis operations and publishing of ArcGIS online content.

How do I now replace my .mxd's which are sharing ArcSDE data with .aprx files? 
Is it possible to publish using arcgis server on ArcGIS Pro?

Originally I thought I would just share the data stored in ArcSDE using ArcGIS Pro in a webmap, that would mean the data is no longer upto date once we make changes to the data in ArcSDE.

Comment: Perhaps be aware of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143653/publishing-map-from-arcgis-pro-to-arcgis-for-server-as-map-service but that may be outdated now that ArcGIS Pro 1.3 is released.  Have you tested at 1.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import your existing ArcMap MXDs into ArcGIS Pro. [See this help link](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/projects/add-maps-to-a-project.htm) for more information on the process. With that done, you can save your project. Essentially you've now migrated from MXDs to APRX (projects).

You *cannot publish* from ArcGIS Pro to ArcGIS Server. From ArcGIS Pro you can *share* webmaps or web layers to **ArcGIS Portal** (that means a local portal or arcgis.com). In the scenario you propose, if you're sharing a webmap to arcigs.com, then you're correct; the data becomes static as it's pushed up to that server. If you're making a webmap in your local portal you can setup and reference the data from your enterprise geodatabase, thus the webmap will continue to use data that you make updates too. Its almost the same as publishing a map service to ArcGIS Server, except you're publishing a webmap to Portal. All the same concepts, just slightly different technologies.